# SQL Oracle Input format

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, format

An existing query being used in Oracle SQL Developer has the Dist_no hardcoded in the line :-

```
WHERE CUSTIMA.BCONFJOB.U##DIST_NO IN ('15','16')
```

How do I request the input from the user while showing how we want it?
I was thinking if possible just taking the two digit numbers, separated by a comma and adding the other formatting in the code but don't know how (it doesn't appear as simple as using the to_date function)

To clarify we have several different tables where districts are stored as either two digits, or two digits followed by "D"

Is there a way to process the Substitution Variable within the query to convert it to the relevant format independent of the input, ie for one table '10','16' will work, the other, '10D,'16D' but have it so the user only has to supply 10,16 and the query does the rest.

Basically, how do I take substitution variables and convert them to the relevant table format, ie adding an appropriate suffix where necessary

Comment: how is the use going to be asked for the input ? are you simply going to hand over the query and pass ask the user for the necessary values? are you using this on a web app? you can use `bind` variables and the user would be prompted for values in oracle sql developer.

Comment: The user would be simply running it in SQL Developer and if I was able to set it up getting a simple prompt, with a suggestion of how to format it, ie separated by a comma, but not having to enter the ' before and after the values as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass the list of values as a substitution variable and use `TABLE` function to convert them to rows to do comparison. Here I use Oracle's  built-in collection type `sys.odcinumberlist`. You may use a custom type for the actual data type you are passing as input

```
SQL> select employee_id,last_name,salary from employees
        where employee_id
      IN ( SELECT * FROM sys.odcinumberlist(&emplist) --substitution variable

Enter value for emplist: 100,101,102  --Simply pass comma separated values
old:select employee_id,last_name,salary from
employees
  where employee_id
  IN ( SELECT * FROM sys.odcinumberlist(&emplist)
)
new:select employee_id,last_name,salary from
employees
  where employee_id
  IN ( SELECT * FROM sys.odcinumberlist(100,101,102)
)

EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                     SALARY
----------- ------------------------- ----------
        100 King                           24000
        101 Kochhar                        17000
        102 De Haan                        17000
```

if you want to pass multiple dates, you may use `odcivarchar2list` with the `to_date` function.

```
SQL> SELECT  to_date(column_value,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
 FROM sys.odcivarchar2list(&emplist) ;
Enter value for emplist: '2019-01-01','2019-02-02' --passing dates as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

old:SELECT  to_date(column_value,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
 FROM sys.odcivarchar2list(&emplist)
new:SELECT  to_date(column_value,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
 FROM sys.odcivarchar2list('2019-01-01','2019-02-02')

TO_DATE(
--------
01-01-19
02-02-19
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the table is supposed to be part of the query here. I was hoping there is a simple substitution process where the user is prompted to enter :-15,16 and I can then format it to be what the sql requires to function :-'15','16'. This query also has to work for all the other district combinations as well, hence the need for requesting the parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
n number(5);
BEGIN
n:=:n;
IF (n MOD 2 =0) then
dbms_output.put_line('even');
else
dbms_output.put_line('odd');
end if;
end;
/
```

this code works only in oracle database